# Building older NetBeans project in bash leads to error

Tags: java

I am opening an older NetBeans project and I want to build it using `ant` in `bash` with debian. However, when I try to run `ant`, I get this error

> BUILD FAILED
>   /home/karelbilek/NetBeansProjects/oldProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:528:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/karelbilek/NetBeansProjects/oldProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:261:
>   Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on
>   the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is
>   currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre"

What does that mean? What should I do? In "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre" there seems to be an actual JRE when I look there, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pointing to a JRE (Java *runtime environment*) but not a JDK (Java *development kit*).

Only the JDK contains the compiler (`javac`). The JRE is used for running Java programs but doesn't carry the extra components of the JDK (compiler etc.)

Comment: Oh yes. When I installed `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` everything worked. I feel embarassed for such a basic mistake :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it happened for me and i got through it by installing the jdk

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

After installing jdk, the classpath executed right